# Flutter - Bottom Overflowed By 119 Pixels

Tags: dart, flutter

I had an error "*Bottom Overflowed by 199 pixel*" when creating an Image inside the `ListView`, and after i google it, all of them suggest me to add:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
```

But, it **doesnt work!** The error is still there.

[image]

`SafeArea` widget is also doesnt solve the problem. Here is the short code version of my layout:

```
body: ListView(
         children:<Widget> [
           new Container(
             child: new Stack(
               children:<Widget> [
                 //THE WIDGET
                 new Container(), //THE BACKGROND IMAGE
                 new Positioned(
                   child: Column(
                     children:<Widget>[
                         new Transform(),
                         new FadeTransition(),
                         new FadeTransition(),
                         Divider(),
                         new Row(),
                         //THE IMAGE THAT I WANT TO ADD
                         new Container(
                           height: 360.0
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                               image: Assetimage('lake.jpg)
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

put your contents in a **`SingleChildScrollView`** and add **`ConstrainedBox`** like this:

```
body :SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(),
            child: ListView(
         children:<Widget> [
           new Container(
             child: new Stack(
               children:<Widget> [
                 //THE WIDGET
                 new Container(), //THE BACKGROND IMAGE
                 new Positioned(
                   child: Column(
                     children:<Widget>[
                         new Transform(),
                         new FadeTransition(),
                         new FadeTransition(),
                         Divider(),
                         new Row(),
                         //THE IMAGE THAT I WANT TO ADD
                         new Container(
                           height: 360.0
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                               image: Assetimage('lake.jpg)
```

This is may make your screen scrollable and adding constraint will make it finite scroll.

Comment: It gives infinite scrolling for large screen deivce but for small screen device its still same throwing error! 
I used Padding -> SingleChildScrollView -> ConstrainedBox -> Column -> Column + widgets.

As per my design structure there is two parts in screen one part have all widgets which  will cover top portion and bottom portion should have button. 
In large screen there is space between them and in small device they stick together (no space between) but in small device this should allow to scroll user.

Answer (score 68):

Use Scaffold property "resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false" and "SingleChildScrollView" as parent of Scaffold body:

```
    home: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Registration Page"),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: RegisterUserPage(),
          )),
```

Comment: only `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` worked because of positioned design I have. thanks

Comment: This property no longer exists, but this `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` exists

Comment: Set ```resizeToAvoidBottomInset = false```  (```resizeToAvoidBottomPadding``` is deprecated.)

Answer (score 14):

Nothing, Just include your **widget** inside **Expanded** like this

```
 Expanded(
    child: sectionList(),
  )
```

//this solved my issue

Answer (score 4):

**Just Use**

## SingleChildScrollView()

### like as

```
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child:  Column(
        children: [
          widgetClassSectionButton(),
          listAttandance.isNotEmpty ? headLineContainer() : msgNothingToShow(),
          listAttandance.isNotEmpty ? widgetStudentList():widgetMsgEmpty(),
          CustomButton("Submit Data",context)
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,` in Scaffold and wrapping the first child in the body with `SingleChildScrollView` solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks! only wrapping the first child with SingleChildScrollView is perfectly working for me

Answer (score 2):

The parameter in scaffold works for me, envolve your widget for this error.
      **singlechildscrollview**

Answer (score 2):

This works for me for long form:

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(...
```

Answer (score 1):

This aligns the item from bottom to top:

```
child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                reverse: true,
```

Answer (score 1):

This is How I solved it, adding a `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` inside `Scaffold()` and using `SingleChildScrollView()` inside the body.

```
 return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Quotes"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: quotes.map((quote) => quotesTemplete(quote)).toList(),
        ),
      )
    );
```